# Python packages installing error in deep-learning environment

Tags: python, pip, deep-learning

When I am installing the new package in my deep-learning environment it gives me this error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 32]
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process:  Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Please help to resolve this

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: yes but it is still giving the save error

Comment: Have you tried to close all python processes before trying to install new package?

Comment: yes @Muser but its not being installed

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install the package to a system folder which you don't have permissions to write to.
You have three options(use only one of them):

**1-setup a virtual env to install the package (recommended):**

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate 
then:
Install your package using python -m pip install <name_package>
```

**2-Install the package to the user folder:**

Install your package using:

```
` python -m pip install --user <name_package>
```

**3-use sudo to install to the system folder (not recommended):**

```
`sudo python -m pip install  <name_package>
```

Comment: i have tried 3 all above but it's still giving the same error

Comment: Which version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

terminal one as administrator if using Windows and use ubuntu before command use sudo.